# latex problem showing $ missing

Tags: math-mode, errors

```
f \left( O \right.) $\rightarrow$ f \left( I \right.)
```

[image]

Comment: why did you tag this as biblatex?

Comment: `\left(` and `\right)` commands are only available into math mode. By the way, you don't need them in an equation like that.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. There's more than one possible way that you could fix this, but it's hard to know what's best without more context.

Answer (score 1):

You may avoid `\right` and `\left`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$f ( O ) \rightarrow f ( I )$
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

If you use `\left(` and `\right)` you should be in math-mode but not recommended:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$f \left( O \right.) \rightarrow f \left( I \right.)$
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

Comment: or better `$f (O) \rightarrow f  (I)$ `  Do you really want the `(` from O matched with the `)` from I ????

Comment: Should that be `\right)` instead of `\right.` in the second example?

Comment: @Mico both worked on my computer. I'm dumb and so copy paste the code from the OP and he wrote `\right.)`